# QtCreator with MinGW : How to make compiler optimization

Tags: optimization, mingw, qt-creator

I am using QtCreator on windows, and I would like to know how to make my compiler optimize the output.

My understanding is that MinGW is a port of GCC. So, I should be able to use arguments such as **-O2**. However, in the "Projects" bar, the only things I see are :

- Build step for qmake (probably not here, qmake is about the .pro files / MOC / Qt stuff ...)
- Build step for mingw32-make (probably)
- Clean steps (probably not)

So, I tried to add -O2 in the "Make arguments" box, but unfortunately, I get an error "invalid option --O"

---

For anyone interested, I was trying to make an implementation of [the Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) because I read that :

> The Ackermann function, due to its definition in terms of extremely
>   deep recursion, can be used as a benchmark of a compiler's ability to
>   optimize recursion

The code (which doesn't really use Qt) :

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int nbRecursion;
int nbRecursions9;

int Ackermann(int m, int n){
    nbRecursion++;
    if(nbRecursion % 1000000 == 0){
        qDebug() << nbRecursions9 << nbRecursion;

    }
    if(nbRecursion == 1000000000){
        nbRecursion = 0;
        nbRecursions9++;
    }

    if(m==0){
        return n+1;
    }
    if(m>0 && n>0){
        return Ackermann(m-1,Ackermann(m, n-1));
    }
    if(m>0 && n==0){
        return Ackermann(m-1,1);
    }
    qDebug() << "Bug at " << m << ", " << n;

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    nbRecursion = 0;
    nbRecursions9 = 0;

    int m = 3;
    int n = 13;

    clock_t begin = clock();
    Ackermann(m,n);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    qDebug() << "There are " << CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " CLOCKS_PER_SEC";
    qDebug() << "There were " << nbRecursions9 << nbRecursion << " recursions in " << elapsed_secs << " seconds";

    double timeX = 1000000000.0*((elapsed_secs)/(double)nbRecursion);
    if(nbRecursions9>0){
        timeX += elapsed_secs/(double)nbRecursions9;
    }

    qDebug() << "Time for a function call : " << timeX   << " nanoseconds";

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-O2` is used by default when you do a release build. Only debug builds don't use optimization. Regardless, if you want to use specific compiler options, you do so in the project file (`*.pro`) itself, by appending your options to the `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE` (for C files) and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE` (for C++ files). For example:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -O3 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -fomit-frame-pointer
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O3 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -fomit-frame-pointer
```

If you really want to use some specific options always, regardless of whether it's a debug or release build, then append to `QMAKE_CFLAGS` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` instead. But usually, you'll only want optimization options in your release builds, not the debug ones.